# How do I add a task which execute excutable jars in my customed gradle plugin

Tags: plugins, gradle

I know I could define a task whose type `JavaExec` in `build.gradle` and configure some jar classpath and args.
But how do I do this in groovy plugin code. Do I need to extend a JavaExec task? Then how's it like.
My case here would be a command like below:

```
java -jar moco-runner-0.10.2-standalone.jar http -p 12306 -c test_data/b2/v9470/b2_moco.json
```

Comment: You do not *have to* extend javaExec, but it is probably the simplest way to achieve this. BTW if you want to run your java process in a separate JVM, you should look into ProcessBuilder.

Comment: Thanks, finally I used the way you suggest